# Aerospike: Getting writing pickled failed (Disk & Memory Available > 70%)

Tags: aerospike

I am using 2 node cluster. After migrating from 3.6.3 to 3.7.3, I am getting following error in aerospike.log

(thr_rw.c::2861) [NOTICE] writing pickled failed(-1)::

Available space and memory are more than 70%.  Though my unit tests are getting passed, I am worried on unexpected issues in future due to this. I am also using LDT (LSTACK)

Kindly Help.

Comment: Update: Also I am getting below error using asmonitor frequently. Working sometimes and after few seconds, throwing below error.

request to  127.0.0.1 : 3000  returned error
skipping 127.0.0.1:3000

While working I am getting proper message like below.

2 hosts in cluster: 202.102.207.10:3000,202.102.207.11:3000

Comment: Also CPU usage on one of the server hits more than 1100% and another server 500% +.  I am posting this update just 1hr after restart.

Comment: There should be a warning that precedes that message.

Comment: Also should note that LSTACK are amound data types currently in the process of being deprecated, please see [3.5.2 release notes](http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#3.5.2).

Comment: @kporter, I am not seeing any warning after it.
Feb 08 2016 21:53:31 GMT: INFO (rw): (thr_rw.c::2861) [NOTICE] writing pickled failed(-1):<Digest>:0x0e7e607c2e4e365bbfd469477485b9d5228a7199

Feb 08 2016 21:53:31 GMT: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c::2088) device /opt/aerospike/data/scm.dat: used 11136, contig-free 20478M (163831 wblocks)
, swb-free 0, w-q 0 w-tot 0 (0.0/s), defrag-q 0 defrag-tot 1 (0.0/s) defrag-w-tot 0 (0.0/s)


Feb 08 2016 21:53:34 GMT: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c::2088) device /opt/aerospike/data/test.dat: used 256, contig-free 16382M (16382 wblocks), 
swb-free 0, w-q 0 w-...

Comment: Also I mentioned there is 70% space left on both disk and  memory.

Comment: 1) does this appear when running test against 3.6.3? 2) There should be a warning before that message, I didn't see a path to that message without a warning. 3) Could you be writing larger than your configured write-block-size?

Comment: @kporter, 1)No. I didnt see this on 3.6.3. I was seeing this while restarting after upgrade to 3.7.3.  2) No warning after the message. 3) There were no new writes after upgrading to 3.7.3.      The cluster was stable now after 5 hours after upgrade. I am not seeing this error any more.  Can you please have a look at the issue which I posted on github somewhat relating to this: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server/issues/115

Comment: 3) Sorry to keep hammering this, but you say there isn't a warning **after** the message and there wouldn't be. I am looking for a warning **before** the message. 4) How many times does this message appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to worry on this. The Notice vanishes once the migration got completed.  Checked it couple of times in production.